# How to make both scenes appear at same time in javaFx

Tags: javafx

This is my code by right clicking in the first scene the second scene appears but the thing is first scene goes down, is there any solution that the first scene does not go down and second scene appears on it

```
@FXML
private void newFolder(MouseEvent event) {

    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {

    Label secondLabel = new Label("I'm a Label on new Window");

    StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
    secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);

    Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 400, 400);

    // New window (Stage)
    Stage newWindow = new Stage();
    newWindow.setTitle("Second Stage");
    newWindow.setScene(secondScene);

    // Set position of second window, related to primary window.
    newWindow.setX(200);
    newWindow.setY(100);
    newWindow.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: The same `Stage` cannot have two `Scene`s showing at the same time. If you want to add additional nodes to an existing `Scene` then add them to the appropriate parent, as Ahmed Emad suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018266/6395627).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put two nodes above of each other you don't have to have another `Scene` you can just add your `Node`s to the same root inside the Scene

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().addAll(node1,node2);

Scene scene1 = new Scene(root,400,400);

FirstStage.setScene(scene1);
```

unless you want to have more than one screen that's a different thing I can't get exactly what you want from your question